# viewModel not returning updated response

Tags: android, android-mvvm

The user opens a login activity. Enter mobile and **wrong** password. All goes well and toasts show "Incorrect user/password."

Now in the same activity, the user enters **correct** credentials. But it still toasts show "Incorrect user/password." But if he goes back to any other activity and comes back all work well.

This is my code snippet.

Repository

```
public class LoginRepository {
    @Inject
    @Named("with_out_authorization")
    RestInterface restInterface;

    private static final String TAG = LoginRepository.class.getSimpleName();
    private static LoginRepository loginRepository;

    public LoginRepository() {
        AppController.getInstance().getNetComponent().inject(this);
    }

    public synchronized static LoginRepository getInstance() {
        //TODO No need to implement this singleton in Part #2 since Dagger will handle it ...
        if (loginRepository == null) {
            if (loginRepository == null) {
                loginRepository = new LoginRepository();
            }
        }
        return loginRepository;
    }

    public LiveData<LoginResponse> tryLogin(String mobileNumber, String password) {
        final MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Call<LoginResponse> call = restInterface.Login(mobileNumber, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse response:: " + response);
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    data.setValue(response.body());
                }
                else{
                    data.setValue(null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                data.setValue(null);
            }
        });

        return data;
    }
}
```

View Model

```
public class LoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final LiveData<LoginResponse> loginResponseObservable;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginViewModel";

    public LoginViewModel(Application application, final String mobileNumber, final String password) {
        super(application);

        // If any transformation is needed, this can be simply done by Transformations class ...
        loginResponseObservable = LoginRepository.getInstance().tryLogin(mobileNumber, password);
        Log.e(TAG, loginResponseObservable.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Expose the LiveData so the UI can observe it.
     * */
    public LiveData<LoginResponse> getLoginResponseObservable() {
        return loginResponseObservable;
    }

    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
        @NonNull
        private final Application application;
        private final String mobileNumber;
        private final String password;

        public Factory(@NonNull Application application, String mobileNumber, String password) {
            this.application = application;
            this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new LoginViewModel(application, mobileNumber, password);
       }
    }
}
```

Activity

public void btnLoginClicked(View v) {

```
    if (!validateForm() || !isConnected())
        return;

    String mobileNumber = editTextMobile.getText().toString();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    LoginViewModel.Factory factory = new LoginViewModel.Factory(getApplication(),
            mobileNumber, password);

    final LoginViewModel viewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    observeLoginViewModel(viewModel);
}

private void observeLoginViewModel(LoginViewModel viewModel) {
    // Update the list when the data changes
    viewModel.getLoginResponseObservable().observe(this, new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable LoginResponse loginResponse) {
            Utility.displayToast(loginResponse.getMessage());
            if (loginResponse.getCode() == HttpStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL) {
                updatePreferences(loginResponse);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMain.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What is not correct in this implementation? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you've put your code:

```
loginResponseObservable = LoginRepository.getInstance().tryLogin(mobileNumber, password);
```

inside your ViewModel constructor. But as you may see, this constructor is invoked only once, at first attempt to get viewModel instance in your activity:

```
final LoginViewModel viewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(LoginViewModel.class)
```

At next attempts (after second Button click, for example) you'll get the same instance of ViewModel (let's say, that ViewModelProviders here is kinda HashMap and LoginViewModel.class - is the key to return needed ViewModel. So at first attempt this HashMap doesn't contain your ViewModel, that's why constructor is invoked, all next attempts it will return the existing ViewModel). Factory here - is just a way to put arguments to ViewModel's constructor, but it's not a guarantee that ViewModel would be recreated.

So you could remove your code

```
loginResponseObservable = LoginRepository.getInstance().tryLogin(mobileNumber, password);
```

into some another ViewModel's public method and call it each time after Button was clicked